# Mock MsalService in Angular Jest

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, azure-ad-msal

I have a Test in Angular that looks like this. But it always fails because I cannot mock the MsalService correctly.

```
export class MockedMsalService extends MsalService {}

 describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NavbarComponent],
      imports: [
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MsalService, useClass: MockedMsalService },
        { provide: Router, useClass: RouterMock },
        { provide: UsersService, useClass: UsersServiceMock },
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When I try to run the test I get the error: **NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MsalService -> InjectionToken MSAL_INSTANCE -> InjectionToken MSAL_INSTANCE]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MSAL_INSTANCE!**

I would be very grateful if someone could help me further

Comment: Post the code for the component you are testing.

Comment: Also is MSAL coming from a module you've forgotten to import?

Comment: I should probably also point out that `export class MockedMsalService extends MsalService {}` isn't mocking anything.  It's providing an identical class.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide all factories wich were declared into your app.module.ts

```
    import {
       MsalGuard,
       MsalService,
       MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
       MSAL_INSTANCE,
     } from '@azure/msal-angular';

     describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
      let component: NavbarComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [NavbarComponent],
          imports: [
          ],
          providers: [
            { provide: MsalService, useClass: MockedMsalService },
            { provide: Router, useClass: RouterMock },
            { provide: UsersService, useClass: UsersServiceMock },
            {
              provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
              useFactory: MSALFactory, // your app.module.ts factory
            },
            {
              provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
              useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory, // your app.module.ts guard factory
            },
             MsalService,
             MsalGuard,
          ],
          schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        }).compileComponents();
      });
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is in the comment: `MockedMsalService extends MsalService` doesn't mock `MsalService`.

To avoid dependency hassle, the best way is to use a mocking library, for example [`ng-mocks`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu).

In this case, your test can look like:

```js
 describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;

  // NavbarComponent stays as it is
  // All dependencies in NavbarModule will be mocks
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(NavbarComponent, NavbarModule));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And to customize mocks, you can use [`MockInstance`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockInstance) or [`MockBuilder.mock()`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder#mock).